# Why listOfFiles is null?

Tags: java, android

Android says, that listOfFiles if null, so what have i done wrong?
I've tried to change getPath to getAboletePath, but it is just the same.
And, i've tried to access /storage/ (whereas SD_PATH is /storage/emulated/0) and i've got a list of 2 folders: emulated and self, both of wich are unaccessible.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    ...

File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        File[] listOfFiles = home.listFiles();
        if(listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0){
            for (File file : home.listFiles()){
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unimusic">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What version of the API are you targeting?

Comment: minSdk is 15, target sdk is 23

Comment: try changing the target SDK to 22. If that works then I will write an answer describing why and how to fix it.

Comment: @curob ty, it works. But why?

Comment: Always check the LogCat for relevant information. EACCESS failures and/or permission failures are explicitely stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This same thing has burned me in the past.

To quote the docs

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

(see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

Reading from the file system is one of the permissions that must now be requested at run time in order to use. This is only an issue if you target SDK 23 or later. So how to fix:

The docs show an example (see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request) for the original) that I have modified for your use case (I have not run this code, but it should be a good starting point). You probably want to request permissions in the `onCreate()` for the Activity that is going to need the permission (in your case the `MainActivity`).

```
// Ask for the read external storage permission
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
    {
        // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
        // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
        // Display a SnackBar with a button to request the missing permission.
        Snackbar.make(layout,
                    "External storage is needed in order to {YOUR EXPLANATION HERE}",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    // Request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                }
            }).show();
        }
        else
        {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
}
```

Comment: It worked, but now I have a new error with requestPermissions. App just crashes with an error Package Installer Program crashed (smth like this, got some translation errors, 'cause I'am using Russian language)

Comment: ok, sry, my fault. I thought that if I am asking for permission it doesn't need to be pre-added to AndroidManifest.xml :D